# model to evaluate disease worsening/improvement after a therapy change

Tags: regression, medical, cox-regression, markov-models, hazard

I have some experience with regression analysis, cox models etc., but I would like to ask which model would suite best to evaluate a chronic disease symptomatic control associated with different drug changes.

Suppose you have a time-series data for several patients, with a categorical variable that indicates a drug (drug A, B, C, D) and an outcome for change from one drug to another that is evaluated on four level:
(0: symptoms increased >50%; 1: symptoms unchanged; 2: symptoms reduced >50%; 3: symptoms disappeared)

Which kind of analysis would you apply to best evaluate which drug is associated with the best symptomatic control (taking into account the duration of symptoms control too)? And possibly filter for covariates such as sex, age etc.

I know it may be a difficult question, but I would really love any kind of help or experience on such bio-statistic models

Thanks a lot in advance